# Pasting text from GoogleDocs into D7 Body field causes imagestyle error?

Tags: 7

Super strange - I'm copying and pasting text from a GoogleDoc into a D7 article post. When I do this and publish my article, it drops onto the main page into a slider that I've created via a View. This works seamlessly usually, however when I paste the text from the googledoc, it actually distorts my entire main page - seemingly stripping the image styles from my other article posts in the slider, thus, ruining my slider? Any idea why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: It's probably producing dodgy HTML for whatever reason  - check the markup against a validator to be sure

Comment: @Clive Totally the case I'm sure - how do I check it against a validator? And is there anyway to allow for copy/pasting from a google doc?

Comment: validator.w3.org is a good one, I'm sure there are plenty more a search for "find broken HTML" or similar would show up. I'm afraid I haven't tried copying from a gdoc before but there did always used to be a "paste from word" option if that's a viable option

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck exporting the Google Doc to "RTF" format first then copy + pasting that format into the article body.

You could also try the "Paste without formatting" option, such as `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+V` or `Ctrl+Shift+V` but would need to re-add the formatting (headings etc..) with that approach.

There may also be some WYSIWYG toolbar options to paste with various formatting options (paste from word, paste as plain text etc..)